# Crear canvas con ID segun array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código y luego en una función fuera de todas estás funciones quiero hacer un getElementById, pero los canvas creados  no tiene ID , me dijeron que deberia agregarle id dentro de la funcion per, pero estoy desorientado, si alguien sabe porfavor ayuda.

**Codigo**:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

        function per() {
            console.log("per()");
             var $canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>').css({
                'border-radius': '5px',
                'padding': '0',
                'margin': '0',
                'width': '200px',
                'height': '200px',
                //'position': 'absolute',
                'right': '15px',
                'bottom': '15px',
                'background-color': 'blue'
            });
          $('body').append($canvas);

        }

        $('body').append('<canvas id="minimap"></canvas>');

            $('#minimap').css({
                'background': 'rgba(1,1,1,0.7',
                'border-radius': '0px',
                'border': '1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2)',
                'padding': '0',
                'margin': '0',
                'width': '200px',
                'height': '200px',
                'position': 'absolute',
                'right': '15px',
                'bottom': '15px'
            });
           b.forEach(per);


    });

function obtener() {

document.getElementById(que hago?)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la creacion del canvas:

```
var $canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>').css({
```

le añades el ID.

```
var $canvas = $('<canvas id="ID"></canvas>').css({
```

pero ten en cuenta que el ID tiene que ser unico asi que en la funcion `per` deberias recibir el ID que quieres ponerle:

```
function per(id) {
...
var $canvas = $('<canvas id="' + id + '"></canvas>').css({
```

y en la llamada:

```
b = [1,2,3]; //por ejemplo

b.forEach(function(elem) {
    per("subcanvas" + elem); //id quedaria "subcanvas1", "subcanvas2", ...
});
```

Comment: gracias y en la llamada de document.getelementbyid , pondria cada uno de los canvas? osea getElementById('subcanvas1') o directamente $canvas ?

Comment: y el  $('body').append($canvas); lo dejo como esta?

Comment: @EduardoSebastian si, en la llamada tienes que poner el que quieras llamar ( ej: `getElementById('subcanvas1')`), ya que `$canvas` es la variable de la funcion `pre` y no tienes acceso desde tu `getElementById` ahi abajo. El `append` está bien así

Comment: he puesto asi y me dice "Cannot read property 'getContext' of null" , nosé que hago mal , si podrias ayudarme el error está en la linea 162 de este archivo http://ogar.pw/js/2.js , exactamente en:  var a = document.getElementById('sub1');

Comment: @EduardoSebastian no encuentra ningun elemento con ese id

Comment: pues lo hice como tu lo hiciste, podrias ayudarme porfavor? , si vas aca: http://ogar.pw/client/t.html  , te muestra el error en la consola de chrome , que debo hacer? porfavor

Comment: agradeceria muchisimo tu ayuda lois6b

Comment: @EduardoSebastian quiero ayudarte, pero asi no funciona [es.so]. tu has hecho una pregunta y yo la he respondido :/

Comment: oh, te entiendo pero podrias decirme almenos como podría arreglar el error? porque me sale null si se supone que sí crea los canvas con su id? pienso que es algo del scope o algun error lógico

Comment: @EduardoSebastian te aconsejo que pongas `console.log` en cada funcion para que sepas qué está pasando y que valores hay. asi te aseguras que el id que estás poniendo es `sub1`. Suerte

Comment: gracias intentare solucionarlo