# Como obtener la id de los elementos creados?

Tags: javascript, jquery

En una pregunta anterior me han dado este código y tengo una problema que es como poder mostrar el id de cada elemento creado o como obtener la id( lo que pasa es que necesito hacer un if). Los canvas se crean en la funcion per.

```
b = [1,2,3,4,5];

    $(document).ready(function(){

        function per() {
            console.log("per()");
             var $canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>').css({
                'border-radius': '5px',
                'padding': '0',
                'margin': '0',
                'width': '200px',
                'height': '200px',
                //'position': 'absolute',
                'right': '15px',
                'bottom': '15px',
                'background-color': 'blue'
            });
          $('body').append($canvas);

        }

        $('body').append('<canvas id="minimap"></canvas>');

            $('#minimap').css({
                'background': 'rgba(1,1,1,0.7',
                'border-radius': '0px',
                'border': '1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2)',
                'padding': '0',
                'margin': '0',
                'width': '200px',
                'height': '200px',
                'position': 'absolute',
                'right': '15px',
                'bottom': '15px'
            });
           b.forEach(per);
```

Comment: pero ese codigo que pones no es el actualizado con [mi respuesta ..](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67378/crear-canvas-con-id-segun-array/67391#67391)

Comment: losé, pero alfinal es lo mismo, no? ahora mi problema es obtener esa id creada

Comment: pero si no pones el codigo en el que creas los id's,... no se entiende de que hablas

Comment: podrias editarmela? con tú código? del cel es bastante dificil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el siguiente ejemplo te ilustro como colocar el `id=..` a cada elemento creado y luego como acceder a dichos elementos:

```js
b = [1,2,3,4,5];

    $(document).ready(function(){

        function per(id) {
            console.log("per()");
             var $canvas = $('<canvas id="'+id+'"></canvas>').css({
                'border-radius': '5px',
                'padding': '0',
                'margin': '0',
                'width': '200px',
                'height': '200px',
                //'position': 'absolute',
                'right': '15px',
                'bottom': '15px',
                'background-color': 'blue'
            });
          $('body').append($canvas);

        }

        $('body').append('<canvas id="minimap"></canvas>');

            $('#minimap').css({
                'background': 'rgba(1,1,1,0.7',
                'border-radius': '0px',
                'border': '1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2)',
                'padding': '0',
                'margin': '0',
                'width': '200px',
                'height': '200px',
                'position': 'absolute',
                'right': '15px',
                'bottom': '15px'
            });

         // hacemos un recorrido por el arrays "b"
            b.forEach(

           // creamos una funcion donde pasando como argumento
           // cada elemento "i" encontrado en "b".
              function(i){

             // invocamos la funcion per() donde
             // pasando como argumento el id + i
             // que sera asignado al <canvas id="id+i">
                per("id"+i); // (id1, id2, id[n]..)
            });

         // una vez creado los canvas
         // buscamos en el DOM todos los <canvas>
         // donde el id comience por id*
            $("canvas[id^=id]")

           // por cada elemento encontrado en el DOM
              .each(

             // ejecutamos una funcion
                function(){

               // donde desplegamos la propiedad "id" de cada elemento
                  console.log($(this).prop("id"));

               // modificamos el borde de cada canvas
               // a 10px en rojo solido

               // con jQuery
                  $(this).css({
                    border:'10px solid rgba(255,0,0,1)'
                  });

               // con JS
                  document.getElementById(this.id).style.border="10px solid rgba(255,0,0,1)";
                  
                  
                  
              });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: que bien, me podrias explicar el código para así aprender porfavor? y como sería para hacer un for para cada elemento? osea, necesito EN OTRA FUNCION APARTE , hacer document.getElementById con cada id de los canvas creados, y a cada canvas hacerle un borde rojo por ejemplo, porfavor ayuda con explicacion he visto que tu si sabes, gracias

Comment: Ok, te lo explicare, solo dame un segundo.

Comment: okey gracias:D¡

Comment: Revisa nuevamente el código, te deje al final un ejemplo de como modificar el color del borde tanto en `jQuery` como en `JavaScript`, espero esto te ayude, Saludos!! ;))...

Comment: vayaa¡! que bien explicado, mi única duda es si podria realizar lo del borde fuera de todas estas funciones en una funcion aparte y lo del ^= es un operador? , muchas graias

Comment: Efectivamente, una vez que haz creado los elementos en el **DOM** puedes acceder a ellos desde otra función, el **`^=`** es un [selector de jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) y se utiliza para seleccionar aquellos elementos del **DOM** que comienzan con un valor dado en la expresión ***[nombre^=valor]***, ejemplo: `<input name="linea01">` entonces: `$("input[name^=linea]")` me trae todos aquellos input cuyo nombre comienzan por linea, me alegra que te haya servido y recuerda calificar la respuesta que se ajuste mas a una solución al problema, Saludos!! ;))..